# Session time out with Wicket

Tags: wicket

Recently Wicket put me in another problem of Session out. In normal web application what we do is simply declare session-timeout in web. xml and it works fine for us. But in wicket specifying session timeout in web.xml is not working anymore. But I need session time out for my application badly. Also I can't implemt Ajax Behavior or Ajax Timer for every class to check the session time out. That why I need some ay out to implement session time out for my program to work. Any help is appreciated.

My wicket version is 6.3.0.

Comment: I use session timeout in web.xml and `setMaxInactiveInterval` (user configurable duration) with Wicket since 1.4 (to 1.5.x) without any problem. What version are you using ?

Comment: My wicket version is 6.3.0

Answer (score 1):

Wicket does not manage session duration at all. I think you've misconfigured your servlet container. Try with an empty Wicket project to verify what I say.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to handle session timeout you can set handler in the `Application` `init` method:

```
getApplicationSettings().setPageExpiredErrorPage(MyExpiredPage.class);
```

More info [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/error-pages-and-feedback-messages.html).

Comment: Expired page is very different to expired session. Expired page is when a saved page can no longer be found in the page cache and so needs to be re-rendered from scratch. This can occur even if the session is not expired. Session expiry is managed by the app container (e.g. Tomcat) but you can put hooks in a Wicket app to detect session expiry.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to do it programmatically...

This is how I did it using `Wicket 1.5.7` (Pax-Wicket) and the `servlet-api`. I placed this code in the base page class of my application in which all pages extend.

```
int sessionTimeout = // session timeout
Request request = RequestCycle.get().getRequest();
if(request instanceof WebRequest) {
  ServletWebRequest wr = (ServletWebRequest) request;
  HttpSession session = wr.getContainerRequest().getSession();
  if(session != null) {
    session.setMaxInactiveInterval(sessionTimeout);
  }
}
```